# AWS AMI Optimization for Unreal caches

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, unreal-engine5

I am using Unreal with Pixel Streaming on the AWS servers.

Currently, when a new user accesses my website, I spin off a new instance from a new AWS AMI. The problem is that it takes too long (5 minutes) for Unreal to start on the new instance. Every time Unreal restarts on a new virtual machine, it needs to recompile all shaders and load them into cache from scratch.

Is there a way to store this data in the AWS AMI so that it doesn’t need to be compiled from scratch every time a new instance is launched?

Comment: You can keep the instance in a stopped state until it's needed. This can be automated with the AWS CLI.

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from hybernation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-hibernate-overview.html

Comment: What would happen if you ran Unreal for the first time, then Stopped the instance and created an AMI from it. Would that allow future instances built from that AMI to use the cached information?

Comment: I would suggest looking into https://scalablestreaming.io, they offer pre-configured kubernetes deployments on several cloud platforms (AWS, CoreWeave), with lifetime management, instance authentication, etc. An instance can spin up for up to a minute, but taking into account all the necessary unavoidable things that need to happen, hard to get it under that in a scalable way. At the core of the thing AFAIK is the https://unrealcontainers.com/ technology which is now fully supported in-engine to containerize UE apps.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the recompiling of shaders, you should [package your project](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/packaging-unreal-engine-projects/), as if you were distributing it as binaries.

With the packaged project, you can then [create a custom AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html) containing the binaries and necessary scripts to start the project. Using this approach, you should be able to get Unreal’s start times down to within 30 seconds, once the instance has started. Keeping your AMI small will help to reduce instance start times and you may also want to look into [warm pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-warm-pools.html).

To further reduce loading times, you can look into [optimising your project loading times](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/testing-and-optimizing-your-content/), using normal techniques for distributed games, such as Pak files and level streaming.

There are also other options which may be more efficient that running directly on AMIs. Using containers with an orchestration layer would allow you to load different projects onto the instances without baking them into the AMI. Another option if you don’t want to run extra instances would be to use a managed Pixel Streaming provider, as efficiency of scale can significantly reduce start times.